# Error trying to move div to the end of a site

Tags: css, html

I am getting an error when trying to send a div to the very end of my site.

I am using a general height:100% and the div then moves to the end of the visible screen, but when I scrolls down to the end of the site, the div remain in the same position.

I want to add the div to the end, but for some reason I couln't do it.

Look at the pic.
 [image: Error with the heigth]

My code: http://www.securebitcr.com/test/site2.php

I appreciate any kind of help with it.

Thanks,

Comment: Looks fine to me on my browser (Chrome 10 Linux). The div is touching the bottom of the browser.

Comment: Could you try this? make your window a little bit shorter ... for you to see the scroll, then reload the site, I have IE8 and firefox4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#footer_dv` has `position: absolute` but you want it to have `position: fixed`. An absolute position is relative to the parent so an absolutely positioned element will move and scroll with its parent; a fixed position is relative to the browser viewport so it won't move.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short 
I like that!, and .. what is I want the div at the end of the site, scrolling down until get with it, but this answer works of course, actually I will use this one.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the position:absolute all together and fix your height style of your body, you have 100%px; make it 100%; and your footer should just float to the bottom.

Comment: Now I see, I just removed the "bottom" option and added the position:absolute, and that's it.